# How to unit test inside this.dataSource.manager.transaction include promise all

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, nestjs, ts-jest

I use nestjs and use jest test api. I use transactions rollback data when save database error.

My function look like :

**Some code**

```
 await this.dataSource.manager.transaction(async (manager) => {
      await Promise.all(
     input.map(async (it) => {
    //some logic handle (check data,some thing)
```

**Unit test**

```
describe('someTest', () => {
    beforeEach(async () => {

      const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
        providers: [
          ExampleService,
          {
            provide: exampleRepository,
            useValue: {
              save: jest.fn(),
              find: jest.fn(),
              softDelete: jest.fn(),
            },
          },
          {
            provide: DataSource,
            useFactory: dataSourceMockFactory,
          },
        ],
      }).compile();

      service = module.get<SomeService>(SomeService);
      repo = module.get<SomeRepository>(SomeRepository);
    });

   it('should successfully when insert db', async () => {
      const service = jest.spyOn(service, 'functionTest');
      await service.functionTest(
        '123',
        someinput,
      );
      expect(service).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
        '123',
        someinput,
      );
    });
```

Class:  **dataSourceMockFactory**

```
export const dataSourceMockFactory: () => MockType<DataSource> = jest.fn(() => ({
  connect: jest.fn(),
  transaction: jest.fn(),
  release: jest.fn(),
  rollbackTransaction: jest.fn(),
  manager: {
    transaction: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
      create: jest.fn(),
    })),
    save: jest.fn(),
  },
}));

export type MockType<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]?: jest.Mock<{}>;
};
```

But when i running test, test case only running await **this.dataSource.manager.transaction(async (manager) => {**
and skip **await Promise.all( or any input.map(async (it) => {.**
It return success and not check All function inside promies and input map. I don't know why. How to test any code in promies.all inside transactions.